# PowerShell script - distinguish between 3 command outcomes

Tags: powershell, conditional-statements

Can anyone tell me why I'm always get the same output result?

```
$syslocal = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter "localaccount=true" |
            where {$_.Disabled -eq $False}
if ($syslocal -eq "") {
    Write-Host "Syslocal Enabled"
    exit 0
} else {
    Write-Host "No Syslocal"
    exit 0
}
```

It just needs to see if a account syslocal exist and if it's enabled or not
with 3 outcomes:

- write host: syslocal does not exist, exit 0
- write host: syslocal exist, but is disabled, exit 0
- write host: syslocal exist and is enabled, exit 1010

But all outcomes are the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `Get-WmiObject | Where-Object` statement finds a match the variable `$syslocal` will contain a list of WMI objects. If the statement doesn't find a match (i.e. no local accounts exist or all of them are disabled) the variable will be empty. Neither an empty value nor an array of objects equal the empty string, so your check will always evaluate to `$false`.

Also, for a 3-way check you need to actually check 3 ways.

Change your code to something like this and it should do what you expect.

```
$syslocal = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter 'localaccount=true'

if ($syslocal) {
    if ($syslocal | Where-Object {-not $_.Disabled}) {
        Write-Host 'Enabled local accounts exist.'
        exit 1010
    } else {
        Write-Host 'Local accounts exist, but are disabled.'
    }
} else {
    Write-Host 'No local accounts.'
}
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

this line is wrong:

```
if ($syslocal -eq "")
```

If it exist it's still not equal to `""`

this should be:

```
if ($syslocal)
```

More details already explained on Ansgar Wiechers Answer...

Answer (score 0):

Well there's this as well.

```
$syslocal = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_useraccount -filter "localaccount=true"
Foreach($account in $syslocal){
    If ($syslocal) {
        if($account.Disabled -eq $true) {
            Write-Host "$($account.name) is currently Disabled"
        } Else {
            Write-Host "$($account.name) is currently Enabled"
        }
    } Else {
        Write-host "Just no..."
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `foreach` loop getting entered at all implies that `$syslocal` is never "falsy" here, so the `Else` branch will never execute. You could move the outer `if` outside the loop.